# Cocoa getting multiple substrings from between 2 characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to have it so that certain characters are a different color if they are between two characters, `<` and `>`. I tried using this method to do it

```
-(NSString*)stringBetweenString:(NSString*)start andString:(NSString*)end fromString:(NSString*)other{
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:other];
[scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];
[scanner scanUpToString:start intoString:NULL];
if ([scanner scanString:start intoString:NULL]) {
    NSString* result = nil;
    if ([scanner scanUpToString:end intoString:&result]) {
        return result;
    }
}
return nil;
}
```

and that does what I want it to, but only for one substring. I have multiple substrings that are between those characters, and would like them all to be a different color. The method I use to change the color is this

```
[self.tv setTextColor:[NSColor redColor] range:[s1 rangeOfString:[self stringBetweenString:@"<" andString:@">" otherString:s1] options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]];
```

where `self.tv` is an `NSTextView`. How do I get the ranges of multiple substrings and change the color of those substrings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `NSScanner` is not the best approach for your case - you are copying a substring out of your string and then searching for that substring within the string to get its range, which is rather indirect. Two alternative approaches:

1. `NSString` has a useful looking `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` method which finds substrings of various kinds and presents them each in turn to a block to process. Unfortunately for you none of the kinds is "text between angle brackets", but you could design a similar method which takes a string and a block and passes each substring in angle brackets in turn to it. How to find the substrings? In this case `NSString` comes to your aid with `rangeOfString:options:range:` - this looks for a string within a given range of another string. If you start looking for your open angle bracket passing as range the whole string you'll get the range of the first angle bracket, if any. Now call it again searching for your closing angle bracket passing as range the string after the opening one. If that finds a closing angle bracket you have your first substring - pass it to your block. Repeat until you stop finding substrings.
2. You can use a regular expression search, see `NSRegularExpression`, to find all the substrings in one go and then process the returned list.

HTH.

Comment: Yea I ended up figuring it out last night using a regex